# SQLite creating an AFTER UPDATE Trigger

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to create an `SQLite` trigger that sets the field `FlagPayment` to `1` automatically every time a player reaches `10` points, however, apparently, I have a syntax error.

```
CREATE TRIGGER aft_update AFTER UPDATE ON Player
FOR EACH ROW WHEN (NEW.ParticipationPoints % 10 = 0) and (NEW.ParticipationPoints > 0)
BEGIN
    UPDATE Player SET FlagPayment = 1 WHERE ID = NEW.ID
END;
```

This is the outcome:

> near "END": syntax error: CREATE TRIGGER aft_update AFTER UPDATE ON
>   Player FOR EACH ROW WHEN (NEW.ParticipationPoints % 10 = 0) and
>   (NEW.ParticipationPoints > 0) BEGIN   UPDATE Player SET FlagPayment = 1
>   WHERE ID = NEW.ID END

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown in the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html), all statements in the trigger body must be terminated with a semicolon:

```
BEGIN
    UPDATE Player SET FlagPayment = 1 WHERE ID = NEW.ID;
END;                                                   ^
```